# Considerations for making a 4-5 cm hole in a steel counter top?

Tags: kitchen-counters, dishwasher

About a year ago, I bought a small counter top dishwasher; the apartment I lived in a the time had a kitchen with a connector for it on back of the tap. I have since moved, and the new apartment's kitchen does not come with the necessary facilities.
My first thought was to buy a tap with the required connector, but since this kitchen is quite old, no modern taps (one large cylinder) fit into the counter (two small holes).
So instead I've prepared a connector for the dishwasher under the sink, and all I need now to get it installed is to make an hole in the counter top to route the plastic water pipe through.

How would I best go about this to make the hole look clean and have a raised edge to prevent leakage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this type of bit. First drill a pilot hole of 3/5mm before using this.

[image]

[Found over here](http://www.telfordgroup.co.uk/acatalog/Drilling_accessories.html)

[or this - but its more difficult](http://www.ehow.co.uk/how_7343612_bore-two_inch-hole-through-wood.html) - It says for wood but you can use them for soft steel as well but you need to constantly lubricate (lots!! dont be shy) the bit/surface to keep it cool using WD40 lubrication oil and drill at a slow speed. This is more dirtier and the edge can be rubbish.

Then you can mount something like this

[image]
[image]

These can be found at furniture shops/ swimming pool shops/ hardware stores.. you will need to find the one you need and possibly DIY it slightly.

Comment: What would you say about something like [this](http://www.clasohlson.se/Product/LargeImageViewer.aspx?Path=/Archive/Images/Products/Hi/30-5045.jpg)?

Comment: Is that some kind of drill bit thing? never seen one before :) couldnt say really.

Comment: Yes. The picture isn't too clear, but it appears to be an adjustable cutting bit with a protective cup around it. Will try this on some sheet metal first. :-)

Comment: Dont forget to lubricate the surface with sprayed oil(i mean spray it while you are cutting).. even if it 'diamond' tipped you need to keep it cool otherwise it wont last the second cut.

Comment: Using the step drill worked out great. Thanks again. My countertop dishwasher has been happily humming for over a week now.